# Spring Data Mongo - Build multifacet dynamically

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to create a query with faceted search where each inner facet is created dynamically from parameters received from an external source.

I'm trying something like this:

```
FacetOperation multipleFacet = null;
for (FacetType newFacet: facetTypeList) {
    List<AggregationOperation> facetParams = getFacetParams(newFacet);
    if (multipleFacet == null) {
        multipleFacet = Aggregation.facet(...).as(...);
    } else {
        multipleFacet.and(...).as(...);
    }    
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. The facet stage created only has the data for the last facet included in the list.

Thanks.

Comment: try to replace `multipleFacet.and(...).as(...);` with `multipleFacet = multipleFacet.and(...).as(...);`